# How to make Command Prefix Case Insensitive

Tags: discord.py, python-3.7

So I'm making my discord bot, it's kinda confidential code, so I was wondering how to make command prefix case insensitive. Thank you very much for answering!

Here is some code:

```
prefixez = json.loads(open('info.json', 'r').read())["prefixes"]
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixez, case_insensitive=True)
```

Comment: thanks @Tomerikoo why didn't i think of that lol

Comment: It seems you're using `case_insensitive=True`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: idk whats happening lol

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have a letter that is in your prefix, like `g!` or `f.`, but you want both the capital version of those prefixes to work, make sure to have an array/list with all the prefixes that you want to be allowed. Something like this:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['prefix1', 'prefix2'])
# You can just put the lowercase and upper case version in the list/array
```

But, let's say you have a prefix that is customizable. Well, it's not too hard to accomplish the same thing:

```py
# Make sure you have your normal prefix stored in a variable
# Here, I am keeping my prefix in the "prefix" variable
upper_prefix = prefix.upper()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=[prefix, upper_prefix])
```

Comment: im so sorry but its kinda hard since its customizable, lets say Funbot. so of course that is around 2^len(pre) so its kinda hard.

Comment: So, the prefix is customizable?

Comment: Well, if it is, I made an edit to my post. See if that helps.

Comment: yep, but what if they do fUnBOt

Comment: Wait, what's the prefix?